# Create a new list of data frames from an existing list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, reshape

```
d1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), val = c(111, 444, 777), month = c( "jan", "Jan" , "jan" ))
d2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), val = c(222, 555, 888), month = c( "feb", "feb" , "feb" ))
d3 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), val = c(333, 666, 999), month = c( "mar", "mar" , "mar" ))

old.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)


s1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "a"), val = c(111, 222, 333), month = c( "jan", "feb" , "mar" ))
s2 <- data.frame(id = c("b", "b", "b"), val = c(444, 555, 666), month = c( "Jan", "feb" , "mar" ))
s3 <- data.frame(id = c("c", "c", "c"), val = c(777, 888, 999), month = c( "Jan", "feb" , "mar" ))

new.list <- list(s1, s2, s3)
```

All data frames in the 'old.list' are the same size with the same unique ids. I am trying to convert 'old.list' to a time series for each unique id where 'month' is the timestamp i.e. 'new.list' without using a for loop.

Additional explanation, nth row of every data frame in 'old.list' are combined to create the new data frames for 'new.list', Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you could `rbind` your list elements and `split` by id:

```r
new.list <- do.call(rbind, old.list)
new.list <- split(new.list, new.list$id)
```

Comment: It is perfect, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your series start in January this should work:

(if not look into the start argument of ts)

```r
d1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), val = c(111, 444, 777), month = c( "jan", "Jan" , "jan" ))
d2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), val = c(222, 555, 888), month = c( "feb", "feb" , "feb" ))
d3 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), val = c(333, 666, 999), month = c( "mar", "mar" , "mar" ))

old.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)

d <- Reduce(rbind,old.list)
d <- split(d$val, d$id)

lapply(d, ts, frequency = 12)
#> $a
#>   Jan Feb Mar
#> 1 111 222 333
#> 
#> $b
#>   Jan Feb Mar
#> 1 444 555 666
#> 
#> $c
#>   Jan Feb Mar
#> 1 777 888 999
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Aksel Thomsen , Thank you it works perfectly.

Comment: @DAL - If the solution works for you, perhaps you could consider upvoting the new members solution even though it isn't the accepted solution.

Comment: I tried upvoting them, but It won't let me because I have less than 15 reps, all solutions work and are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```r
d1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), val = c(111, 444, 777), month = c( "jan", "Jan" , "jan" ))
d2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), val = c(222, 555, 888), month = c( "feb", "feb" , "feb" ))
d3 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), val = c(333, 666, 999), month = c( "mar", "mar" , "mar" ))

old.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

old.list %>% 
  reduce(rbind, by = 'id') %>% 
  filter(id != 'id') %>% 
  group_split(id)


#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   id    val   month
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     111   jan  
#> 2 a     222   feb  
#> 3 a     333   mar  
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   id    val   month
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 b     444   Jan  
#> 2 b     555   feb  
#> 3 b     666   mar  
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   id    val   month
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 c     777   jan  
#> 2 c     888   feb  
#> 3 c     999   mar
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>